# Reducing the verbosity of Linq Joins?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm currently working through figuring out how to replace all of our cross-database joins with Entity Framework and Linq, I've managed to get a section of my code working, but what really makes it a bit annoying is the verbosity and complexity of the joins. Is there any method to simplify the code some, or am I stuck with long, verbose, messy code?

An example:

```
using (var context = new CustomerContext(CustomerID))
using (var e = new eContext())
{
    var globalUserList = e.GlobalLoginCustomerBridges
        .Join(e.GlobalLogins,
            glcb => glcb.glcbr_gl_id,
            gl => gl.gl_id,
            (glcb, gl) => new { glcb, gl })
        .Where(n => n.glcb.glcbr_customer_id == CustomerID)
        .Select(n => new User2
        {
            ID = (int)n.glcb.glcbr_user_id,
            GlobalLogin = n.gl.gl_login_name,
            GUID = n.gl.gl_GUID
        }).ToList();

    var customer = e.Customers
        .Join(e.DatabaseConnectionStrings,
        c => c.DatabaseConnectionID,
        d => d.DatabaseConnectionID,
        (c, d) => new { c, d })
        .Select(n => new Customer2
        {
            ID = n.c.CustomerID,
            Name = n.c.CustomerName,
            DatabaseConnectionName = n.d.DatabaseConnectionName,
            DatabaseConnectionString = n.d.DatabaseConnectionString1,
            GUID = n.c.cust_guid,
        }).ToList().FirstOrDefault(n => n.ID == CustomerID);

    var orgs = context.Organizations
        .Select(o => new Organization2
        {
            ID = o.org_id,
            Name = o.org_name,
        }).ToList();

    var users = context.Users
        .Select(n => new User2
        {
            ID = n.UserID,
            FirstName = n.UserFirstName,
        }).ToList();

    var userList = users
        .Join(globalUserList,
            u => u.ID,
            gl => gl.ID,
            (u, gl) => new { u, gl })
        .Join(context.OrganizationObjectBridges,
            u => u.u.ID,
            oob => oob.oob_object_id,
            (u, oob) => new { u, oob })
            .Where(o => o.oob.oob_object_type_id == 9)
        .Select(n => new User2
        {
            ID = n.u.u.ID,
            GlobalLogin = n.u.gl.GlobalLogin,
            FirstName = n.u.u.FirstName,
            GUID = n.u.gl.GUID,
            Customer = customer,
            Organization = orgs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == n.oob.oob_org_id)
        }).Where(n => !isDisabled != null && n.Disabled == isDisabled).ToList();

    return userList;
}
```

In the snippet above, I've removed ~80% of the code as most of it is simply field mappings, but it's considerably longer than what's displayed.

Comment: As Fabio says in his answer, use navigation properties whenever possible rather than joins. If you're using LINQ-to-SQL start thinking in terms of hierarchies of objects rather than tabular data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the first 2 queries don't need to be joined, because they belong to the same database. Couldn't you use navigation properties instead? Remember to only use join between objects which don't have a physical (navigation properties) relation.

About the last query, you could use linq queries instead of chain methods( which makes the code more readable, in my opinion). It would be something like this:

```
var userList = from user in users
                join gul in globalUserList on user.ID = gul.ID
                join oob in context.OrganizationObjectBridges on user.ID = oob.oob_object.id
                where oob.oob_object_type_id == 9
                select new User2
                {
                    ID = user.ID,
                    GlobalLogin = gul.GlobalLogin,
                    FirstName = user.FirstName,
                    GUID = gul.GUID,
                    Customer = customer,
                    Organization = orgs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == n.oob.oob_org_id)
                };
```

Untested code, I'm sure it won't work. I'm just giving you some ideas.

Comment: Upvote for suggesting using navigation properties. This seems a common problem for people moving from SQL to LINQ.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I had completely forgotten about navigation properties.